# I have two root user in ubuntu do i need to install mysql in both

Tags: mysql

i have installed mysql from one root do I need to install mysql from other root. I am working in project in eclipse. but I can not login into registration page.

Comment: Off topic.  And besides, there is only one root user.  It is "root", uid=0.

Answer (score 0):

The OS "root" and the MySQL "root" are *unrelated* and *unconnected*.

Or do you mean something else by "from one root"?  As in something to do with VMs or chroot?